# Can 11 players make a circle and attack keeping the ball in middle?

Tags: rules, football, trivia

Inspired from a troll in Facebook

> [image]
>
> <sub>credits : [Troll Football](https://www.facebook.com/Troll.Football)</sub>

- Can 11 players from a team create a circle and keep the ball inside
  the circle and play?
- Are there any official rules that disallow such thing?
- Did this kind of thing happen in past?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of this older question: http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3490/is-hiding-the-ball-in-footballsoccer-according-to-the-rules This question seems related, too: http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/413/rules-around-shepherding-in-football

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find the question. Thanks I was looking for the first one.